# How do I balance redox equations with three reactants?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

**Could anybody please explain me the concept of balancing redox reactions with three reactants?** Either some solving steps or even the solution would be very appreciated.
For example, I don't know how to balance this equation:

KBr + $\ce{KMnO4}$ + $\ce{H2SO4}$ $\ce{->}$ $\ce{Br2}$ + $\ce{MnSO4}$ + $\ce{K2SO4}$ + $\ce{H2O}$.

I split it like this:
$\ce{K^+ + Br^- + K^+ + MnO4^- + 2H^+ + SO4^2- -> Br2 + Mn^2+ + SO4^2- + 2K + SO4^2- + H2O}$

And then I am not sure what to do, so I did this:

$\ce{Br^- + e^- -> Br2}$

$\ce{MnO4 + 8H^+ - 2e^- -> Mn^2+ + 4H2O}$

And it does not make sense, because I do not know what to do with $\ce{SO4^2-}$.

Comment: In contrary to some other Q/A or forum sites, answers on CH SE site are figuratively paid by the user's own effort. When you ask, it is expected you have thoroughly searched and thought about the topic, providing explicit summary of partial answers/ideas/thoughts you have got until then. Effort not shown may be considered as effort not done and such a question may get closed. 
[How do I ask a good question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Using photos/screenshots of text alone instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused nor referred in answers.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts and eventually using  [MathJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) for formatting of mathematical/chemical formulas or equations.

Comment: See [chem.libretexts.org: Balancing_Redox_reactions](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Electrochemistry/Redox_Chemistry/Balancing_Redox_reactions) and many more, following [Google: How do I balance redox equations](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+balance+redox+equations). Always search before asking.

Comment: You can find useful  [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: I will provide you with a comprehensive account of what to do with $\ce{SO4^2-}$. Here is what: ***nothing***. It just sits there and does nothing. It is not important. Just write the half-reactions (this you already did, only the electrons are going the wrong way), then balance each half-reaction, then put them together.

Comment: [Related](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150262/balancing-reaction-between-copper-and-nitric-acid-given-the-ratio-of-formed-nitr/150270)

Answer (score 0):

You first focus on the groups that undergo oxidation or reduction. The sulfate does neither, so you can set it aside, just like the potassium cations.

The half reactions you wrote, however, need some work. The oxidation state of manganese in permanganate is +7, so there is a transfer of 5 electrons. For bromine to bromide, the oxidation state changes by one, but there are two bromine atoms, so you are transferring 2 electrons, not 1.

Some reactions have more than one species undergoing oxidation (or reduction). In those cases, it is impossible to have a unique balanced equation. This is not one of these cases, though, so it should be possible to write a unique balanced equation.